# Yaml File to trigger pipeline

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Can someone provide a template of a yaml file to trigger azure pipeline from Java maven project?

I know already how to create pipeline from azure deveops.
But I need the pipeline to trigger from framework every time a new branch is created

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below  yaml file to trigger azure pipeline from Java maven project:

```
 #Maven
 #Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
 #Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
 #https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- {{ branch }}

pool:
  {{ pool }}

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```